# How to implement Speech 'Identification' in Javascript (or a Flask WebApp)?

Tags: javascript, python, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I needed to implement speech 'identification', ie. **Guess if the person who is trying to login, is actually him/her, by matching his/her voice**.
To consider the case, where the app doesn't recognize the person, but the user is himself trying to login, then he may bypass it with a pin, setup during initial settings.

I am using Python and Flask, to build the webapp, and included javascript in the question, so as to know of possible ways in it too.
Till now, i read about it from some sources, but i couldn't arrive at a possible solution, on stack overflow, as well as 'few' blog posts.

The best 'possible' solution i could arrive at was Cognitive Speech Services by Microsoft -
    https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/

I also thought of recording the voice using the Recorder.js, and analyzing at the server end, but couldn't implement it.

So, i wanted a way to implement it on the web app, even a simple gist with a bit of code on using ms cognitive services (i did read pages of the documentation, but it didnt help much), or doing it by python will be helpful.

Comment: Note that doing authentication clientside is insecure. Never trust anything coming from the client except source data (e.g. voice, password...), never processed data (e.g. login successful). If you are using an API for auth, use it from serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/home will be helpful.  Note that there are clickthrough links to the API reference.  It explains the high-level process (use “enrollment” to train).

We have [speaker identification](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Windows), which is distinguishing who is speaking from a group of known voices that you train with.  You need to provide labelled data (meaning examples of a known speaker talking): see https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797.

or
Please follow the below link speech SDK samples.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/

You can use batch transcription api and enable diarization. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and that's what I actually did to implement it in the html.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ram pointed out that we can use the Microsoft Cognitive Services, we used the same to implement it.

First, we needed an API key from Microsoft for the Cognitive Speech Service (they give a 2 keys, and an endpoint for 7 days in a free trial, without any card, and another free version for a year maybe, with card details)
Get the API keys here : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/try/cognitive-services/?unauthorized=1

Then, i went through the documentation of Microsoft, but couldn't really be helped by it.
What helped was this : https://github.com/rposbo/speaker-recognition-api

I went through all files, and the 'needed' part was mainly in the speech-recognition-api-demo-core.js and the demo.html
First understand what it's really doing, then only you can implement it on your page.
That actually concludes the answer, since that's how it 'can' be implemented using Javascript.
Extra - https://github.com/AdityaGupta150/ProtoMain - We have used only the needed part of Robin posbo's code (you won't be able to just copy paste, first understand it), and implemented it, you can see that in templates/verification.html